Conditional Probabilities in the Four-Door Monty Hall Dilemma
I am working on solving the Monty Hall problem with unequal probability distributions. Here is the case:
There are 4 doors (A, B, C, D).
The initial probabilities of each door hiding the prize are:
Door A: 0.1
Door B: 0.2
Door C: 0.3
Door D: 0.4
I want to find the probability of the prize being behind door D given the following situation:

The contestant selects door D.
The host opens doors B and C.

I know the answer is $P(D∣bc) = 0.571$ but I don't know how it is calculated
I have been attempting to solve this using Bayes' formula:
$$P(D∣BC) = \frac{P(BC∣D)*P(D)}{P(BC|A)*P(A)+P(BC|B)*P(B)+P(BC|C)*P(C)+P(BC|D)*P(D)}$$
I am unsure how to calculate $P(BC∣D)$ & $P(BC∣A)$.
I think that $P(BC∣B)$ & $P(BC∣C)$ will be zero because if the prize is behind door B or C, the host will never open those doors.
Could someone explain how to work through this problem?

Although it is not quite specified by the problem, you can assume that the host picks the two doors to open at random among the set of doors that he can reveal, i.e. neither $D$ (which was selected by the contestant) nor the door hiding the price. Now you can check, in either conditional cases, what different scenarios is there for the host to reveal two doors.

You need to specify the rules.  How does Monty choose the doors he opens? Are they selected uniformly at random from the empty doors? Something else? In particular, does he refer to the probabilities as he selects?

This answer assumes that Monty is equally likely to choose any two of the three remaining doors when you have selected the winning door.
Consider $30$ trials.  Of those, the prize is behind door D in $12$ trials and behind door A in $3$ trials.  In $4$ of the $12$ trials where the prize is behind door D, Monty will open doors B and C.  In $3$ of the $3$ trials where the prize is behind door A, Monte will open doors B and C.
In other words, you are correct that $P(BC \mid B)=P(BC \mid C)=0$.  $P(BC \mid A)=1$, and $P(BC \mid D)= \frac 13$.  (The last equation is where I'm using the assumption above.)
Given that Monty has opened doors B and C, those are the only possibilities.  Therefore, given what you know, the probability that the prize is behind door D is $\frac 47 \approx 0.571$.

+1 also : elegant explanation that is simultaneously easy for the original poster to understand.
